# Does nohup work across a pipe?

Tags: linux, bash

If I do

```
nohup cmd1 | cmd2 &
```

is that the same as

```
nohup "cmd1 | cmd2" &
```

?

I would like that I `nohup` everything, as `cmd1` will listen on port 8023.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

No, you need to add the nohup to the commands separately.

Something like this is recommended:

```
nohup sh -c "cmd1 | cmd2" &
```

Or alternatively:

```
nohup $SHELL <<EOF &
cmd1 | cmd2
EOF
```

Comment: can someone please explain what is `$SHELL` and why we need it?

Comment: The `$SHELL` contains your currently running shell, on most Linux systems  this will be `/bin/bash` but it could be `/usr/bin/zsh` or something else. The advantage of using the `$SHELL` variable is that this way the command will be executed using your regular shell settings.

Comment: @RoVo: the `EOF` depends on the earlier `EOF` and is the standard for multiline input in bash-like shells. If you changed the `<<EOF` to something else the `EOF` at the end needs to change too. Which shell (and version) are you using?

Comment: I did not change the first EOF. `EOF` is working, but not `EOF &`. Just opens a new line. I use GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). The first option works for me though, just needed `bash -c` for having bash builtins.

Comment: @RoVo I think I may have placed the `&` at the wrong location with the original answer, try the updated answer :)

Comment: @KévinBerthommier the `&` is placed at the right location. Did you forget the quotes perhaps?

Answer (score 17):

As an alternative to `nohup`, I recommend

```
( cmd1 | cmd2 ) > logfile < /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

By rerouting stdin, stdout, and sterr from the terminal, this achieves much the same effect as nohup with a syntax that I, at least, prefer.

Comment: That doesn't protect the command from the HUP signal like `nohup` does.  You'd need `(trap "" HUP; cmd1 | cmd2 ) </dev/null > logfile 2>&1 &` to do that.

Comment: True, but as written, it does prevent the closing terminal from sending the HUP to the process in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, a process created in this way will still be killed when you close the terminal.

Comment: @scribu In my experience, it does not. I have used this method to continue processes after the terminal closes many times without fail.

Answer (score 3):

You always can create a script file and run it with nohup:

```
echo "cmd1 | cmd2" > nohupScript.sh
nohup nohupScript.sh &
```

Answer (score 2):

You could start your pipe in a `screen` session. Keystroke <kbd>Ctrl-a</kbd> and then <kbd>d</kbd> will detach the screen session from your terminal. You can then safely exit your terminal; the pipe will continue to run. Use `screen -r` to reconnect to the session again.

Answer (score -2):

```
nohup cmd1 | cmd2 &
```

No, I have checked just now this is the as follows

```
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

Comment: @JasmineLognnes link contain same error message which posted along with my answer.