# Send tee command via ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, output, tee

I send a `tee` command from host 1 to host 2:

```
ssh user@host2 '/path/run |& tee myFile.txt'
```

I use `tee` so that I get the output of the binary to be added to `myFile.txt`

The problem I have then is after a bit of time, I want to regain control of my local host without having a lot of printout. So I do CTRL+C. This lets the process on host2 continue to run, which is what I want, but it stops the `tee` process itself, so the file is not populated.

I tried to replace `|& tee myFile.txt'` by `2>&1  myFile.txt' &` but it did not help.

How can I ensure that the file continues to be populated on host2, while regaining control to my session on host1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to record the results in some file (work with IO redirection inside of the `nohup`), you need to enclose all the pipeline in the `nohup`. It does not use shell expansions, since argument is only `COMMAND` `ARGS`, so using a `sh` is a good way:

```
ssh user@host2 'nohup sh -c "/path/run |& tee myFile.txt" &'
```

but note that `nohup` will disconnect the terminal from the command ant it might fail. Useful would be to redirect it directly to the file:

```
ssh user@host2 'nohup sh -c "/path/run &> myFile.txt" &'
```

Inspiration from the [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912092/does-nohup-work-across-a-pipe).

Answer (score 0):

use nohup, screen or tmux for backgrounding a process.

Comment: I tried to use `ssh user@host2 'nohup /path/run |& tee myFile.txt'` and `ssh user@host2 'nohup /path/run 2>&1 myFile.txt'` but it does not work. When I do ctrl+c after launching that, the process continues to run on host2, but the file does not record output anymore.

Comment: 'nohup /path/run >> myFile.txt'