# Grep lines containing string1 OR NOT containing string2

Tags: linux, grep

I need to redirect lines from stdout to a file, but just those containing certain `string1` or not containing certain `string2`. How can I do that? I just know how to do that separatelly (either lines containg a `string1` or lines not containing a `string2`). It doesn't have to be `grep`, just something I can use in a pipe in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -ne 'print if /string1/ || ! /string2/' < file
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `/string1/` is a regex match
- `||` means "or", `!` means "not"

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe to `awk`:

```
 your_process | awk '$0!~/string2/ || $0~/string1/{print $0}'
```

If the line being processed does not contain "string2": `$0!~/string2/`
OR if the line being process does contains "string1":  `$0~/string1/`
Then print the line: `{print $0}`

As @Mischa shared in the comments, you can get very terse with awk. This can be written as:

```
 your_process | awk '/string1/ || !/string2/'
```

Comment: There is `or` in the question not `and`, but I just change `&&` I guess.

Comment: {print $0} is the default. For tersaholics:
   ... | awk '/string1/ || !/string2/'

Comment: @T.Poe Sorry about that. `OR NOT` sounds weird and my brain decided it couldn't handle it. Just change that `&&` to `||` and I think that should work fine for you.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. When I reditect to the file with `>` it doesn't write anything. With `tee` it writes something but it stops writing after a while (very quickly), I don't understand that. I tried it with just one statement, without OR, still nothing. My command literally looks like this: `nohup python ./script.py | awk '!/string/' | tee out.txt` or `> out.txt` instead of `| tee`.

Comment: I believe that's due to your `nohup`. [Check out this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26912092/does-nohup-work-across-a-pipe) for doing a pipe with nohup.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
tail -f {SOMETHING} | grep string1 | grep -v string2 >> /tmp/out.log
```

Comment: it is worth to consider "line buffered" output as you are getting input from `tail` and passing it to 2 `grep` processes. (Hello from Kyiv)

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Main idea - is to use `grep string1` for match desired strings and `grep -v string2` to exclude non-interested strings, all the - rest just for sake of example.